# Could I substitute $i$ in a convergence series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

The question is to calculate the sum of series. The series is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}.$$

**My attempt:**
Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1},$$
take the derivative term-by-term, I have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n-2}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}.$$
Integrate on both sides,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}~\mathrm dx=\frac12(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)).$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-2}}{2n-1}=\frac1{2x}(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)).$$
Substitute $x=i$, I reach
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}=\frac1{2i}(\ln(1+i)-\ln(1-i)).$$

Can I substitute $x=i$ into last equation? Is this valid in the convergent domain?
Having seen the right answer,I presume I think more about it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of convergence
$$\arctan z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
is $|z|\le 1, z\ne i,-i$, so it is valid in your case.

Actually you have written the [logarithm form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Extension_to_complex_plane) of $\arctan$ fuction on $\Bbb C$:
$$\arctan z =\frac i2(\ln(1-iz)-\ln(1+iz))$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}=\frac i2(\ln(1-i\cdot{\color{red}1})-\ln(1+i\cdot{\color{red}1}))=\arctan({\color{red}1})=\frac\pi 4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Very similer to the previous solution, it is a little bit shorter.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\int\limits_0^1(-t^2)^n dt=\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\arctan(1)-\arctan0=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Dirichlet beta function at $\beta(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Now I see your main question. My answer concerns only for the calculation of the sum.